# Regex for uppercase word in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm not very good with regex, so thanks for any help here.

I need to parse a string such as "sign me up for LUNCH" to pull out  the word in uppercase. I'm using Ruby.

So I need something like

```
string = "sign me up for LUNCH"
keyword = string.gsub(/some_rexex/, '')
# keyword should == 'LUNCH'
```

Thanks again for your help

Comment: `[A-Z]+` get 1 to many uppercase ascii letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string.scan` function instead of `string.gsub`  to grab a particular string you want.

```
> "sign me up for LUNCH".scan(/\b[A-Z]+\b/)[0]
=> "LUNCH"
```

`\b` called word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character.

**OR**

```
> "sign me up for LUNCH".scan(/(?<!\S)[A-Z]+(?!\S)/)[0]
=> "LUNCH"
```

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind which asserts that the match wouldn't be preceded by a non-space character.
- `[A-Z]+` Matches one or more uppercase letters.
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead which asserts that the match wouldn't be followed by a non-space character.

Comment: that almost works, but if there is a word after the upercase word it returns that too. ex: "sign me up for LUNCH today" returns "LUNCH today"

Comment: then you need to use string.scan function.

Comment: @DougSteinberg Depending on your input you might want to use `\p{Upper}` (or `[[:upper:]]`) rather than `[A-Z]`, which won’t match e.g. `"inscrivez-moi pour le DÉJEUNER"`

Answer (score 0):

For a regex solution, Avinash Raj definitely has the correct solution. I figured I'd add to his with an alternative solution.

If you wanted to avoid using regex altogether, you can instead iterate over the string in question and simply compare each word to its upcase value.

```
string = "sign me up for LUNCH"
string.split(" ").each do |word|
    if (word == word.upcase)
        puts word
    end
end
```

This method can be helpful if you need to do something with that word or surrounding text as soon as you match it.

Comment: I like this idea. I was thinking of doing something like this too, but it seems like regex is a more efficent way to go